Node JS need to run multiple environment
My node js application works with different environments like (Dev and live) servers. Dev and Live have other credentials. How can I manage that?
I can run different environments but want to run multiple environments on the same server.

Just pass some arguments to your application when you execute it, like you would do with any application. You can use the commander npm package to easily support startup arguments.

Are you referring to using live credentials on the production server and dev credentials on the local server, or are you referring to constructing scripts for both environments in the package.json file?

Look into environment variables, the dotenv package, and .env files.

You can use dotenv without problems, but if you have problems with third-party package, another way is update to NodeJS 21.7.0 or higher. In this version you can substitute that package with a native function. Additionally, you can load multiple env files (I'm not sure if that substitutes all functions of dotenv, but it is an option).
Use this function process.loadEnvFile().

Many will tell you to use dotenv to configure multiple environments, probably key-ing environment variable names with a suffix or something.
I, on the other hand, being the author of wj-config, will recommend it as it can be file-based.
Without knowing more about your setup, I cannot comment further, but wj-config is very flexible and will allow you to get configuration data from many different sources that get consolidated in a single configuration object.  Try it out.

It feels wrong to suggest an obscure module like that, when there is an industry standard that works across all platforms and cloud environments like environment variables. Especially when you are the author of the module. Environment variables were created and are used to handle exactly the situation OP is asking about.

"Obscure", you say.  Is it obscure because...?  Does its extensive documentation make it obscure?  Is it obscure because of its open source nature?  What's obscure about it?  Nothing is obscure about it.  I made an option that is superior to both dotenv and config and v3 will be even superior in terms of TypeScript/Intellisense.  Take it or leave it, but don't catalogue it as obscure,  Obscure and unpopular/unknown are not the same thing.

Obscure as in not widely known about. Chill. No one is questioning the work you put into it. But environment variables are a standard for a reason, got huge improvements recently and is even native to node as of 21.7.0, no need for dotenv or any other external module.
